# From Eclipse to IntelliJ - How to substitute the Add/Remove function to a JBoss Server?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, jboss

I was an Eclipse user and I have switched to IntelliJ.

In Eclipse, I have some JavaEE projects linked between each others, and run on a JBoss Server. I was using the `Add/Remove` functionality to automatically add the EJB to the server. 
 [image]

After that, in the window, it automatically recognize the beans and I can add them to the server.
[image]

I have tried with a war exploded, but I can't find the same module than the module on eclipse.

How can I do the same in IntelliJ because it feels that it's complicated 
[image]

Comment: JBoss Server is only supported in Ultimate version. Are you using this or Community Edition?

Comment: I'm using the Ultimate Edition 2019.3

Comment: I have my JBoss configure in IntelliJ. My screenshots are from "Deployement" tab.

Comment: Do you mean that IDEA doesn't show modules to be added to artifact?

Comment: I mean, I don't find the correct Artefact for JavaEE projects. When i'm doing Web Application Exploded, all WebContent folder is not deployed. I just want to find the equivalent of Eclipse of that (automatic recognize of beans).

Comment: Have you tried JavaEE Exploded?